# How to blur an image drawn on the canvas in kivy?

Tags: python, canvas, widget, kivy

I would like to know how I can blur an image (e.g RoundedRectangle()) drawn on the canvas with

kivy for a shadow effect.

I tried using EffectWidget() but it doesn't work with image drawn on the canvas.

Someone who knows should please give me an example on how to do this or an alternative on how to give buttons shadow effects. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.effectwidget import *
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import *

class bg(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,back_color=[1,0,0,1],border_radius=[5],**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.back_color = back_color
        self.border_radius = border_radius
        with self.canvas.before:
            self.col = Color(rgba=self.back_color)
            self.rect = RoundedRectangle(size=self.size,pos=self.pos,radius=self.border_radius)

class ShadowButton(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,back_color=[0,0,0,1],border_radius=[5],**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.back_color = back_color
        self.border_radius = border_radius

        btn = bg(size_hint=(None,None),size=(100,40),pos=(50,100))

        self.w = EffectWidget()
        self.w.add_widget(btn)
        self.w.effects = [HorizontalBlurEffect(size=20.0),VerticalBlurEffect(size=20)]


class TestPage(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.btn = ShadowButton(size_hint=(None,None),size=(100,40),pos=                (50,100))
        self.add_widget(self.btn)



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TestPage()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an EffectWidget is an appropriate solution, if it didn't work it's probably because you did something wrong.

Comment: Please, help me to know why the rounded rectangle blurred widget is not showing up on the window. I've posted the test code above.